# What does the item 'Treble' do?

Tags: slice-and-dice

What does the item Treble do?  The following description is not clear to me.

> Add *Treble* to the left side.  Other Keywords x2 -> x3

[image: In-game image of item. Add Treble to the left side. Other Keywords x2 -> x3]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SliceAndDice/comments/1bmi9cz/does_anyone_get_how_treble_works/ not  sure what "sides" and "engage" mean since I dont play this game, nor do I get how you are suppose to get that information out of this graphic.

Comment: Note that treble is a keyword rather than an item; the item here is Clef. I would edit the question but I'm not sure if that distinction is part of your confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Other keywords on the same side which contain "x2" are modified to contain "x3" instead.

For example, the Engage keyword is pips x2 if the target is at full health, and Pristine is pips x2 if the user is at full health. If you give Treble to a side which has one of these, then that side's pips will be tripled instead of doubled when the corresponding condition is met.